# Yaesu FT-65R quick function keys: changing values

Tags: yaesu, equipment-operation

I am using a FT-65R radio and loving it much. However I have a problem with assigning
menu items to P1-P4 buttons. If I assign CTCSS menu item to, let's say P2, then after pressing P2 the menu item is correctly recalled.

But I can't figure out how to change individual items (TX/RX tone in this case). Usually it is done by the Fn key, but in this case Fn exits the menu item. What should I do instead?